# Time Dilation and the direct opposite

Tags: quantum-mechanics

// I just looked this up in google

30 kilometers per second
Thus, the surface of the earth at the equator moves at a speed of 460 meters per second--or roughly 1,000 miles per hour. As schoolchildren, we learn that the earth is moving about our sun in a very nearly circular orbit. It covers this route at a speed of nearly 30 kilometers per second, or 67,000 miles per hour.

AND

The speed with which the Sun has to move is an astounding 483,000 miles per hour (792,000 km/hr)! The Earth, anchored to the Sun by gravity, follows along at the same fantastic speed.

AND

The motion that's left must be the particular motion of our Galaxy through the universe! And how fast is the Milky Way Galaxy moving? The speed turns out to be an astounding 1.3 million miles per hour (2.1 million km/hr)!

So all up we are moving very very VERRY fast and the way that Time Dilation is explained is that the faster you go the slower time is relative to someone/thing that is moving slower. (So the atoms animate/decay slower the faster we go towards the speed of light)

OK   NOW for my question!

If we are all ready moving that fast and cosmic speed limit is C
and we calculate the added up speed we are going through the universe.
And travelled directly back the way we come from. Would we get to a much slower speed relative to C thus the atoms speed up in the animation/decay.
And would this be the other end of the scale? 
So coming to a complete stop in the x y z axis of space time Would be the polar end of the scale from the speed of C and would that mean atoms would animate/decay at the speed of c   ect.

sorry for the long post :)

What I am trying to say is as a clock moves faster through space it slows down.
So if we are moving though space at such speed already how slow could we go? and is there a point where the clock was moving though space at little to no speed that time on the clock was at maxim

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot tell what you are trying to ask.

Comment: ok well lets say the speed we are moving through space around the sun + around the galaxy through the universe and we hop in a space ship and don't move so the earth moved away from us at that speed would we get older much faster than the people on earth?

Comment: my point is their a comic speed of decay at the point you come to a complete stop in the x y z in space time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "their a comic speed of decay at the point you come to complete stop in the x y z space time"

Comment: Can you repeat that in english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite understand what you're talking about either, but let me try to clarify one thing. When objects that "move fast" experience time dilation, they don't care what direction the move in. For instance, if we performed your turning around experiment, we would simply slow down, start going in the other direction at the same speed, and the relativistic effects would go back to being the same as they were originally (atoms decaying at the same rate, etc).

Another way to think about this - "speed" here is moving through space. While you are moving through space (even really really fast), time is still marching forwards. It happens that if you move really fast, time moves slower and slower (relative to an observer at rest...), but time is still moving forwards. If you turn around, time still marches forward! No *physical* objects can change this "time moving forward" thing.

I'll keep going, to talk about your atomic decay thing. Say we take a measurement, and we learn that some atom decays in 1.0 s. Now we put that atom on a spaceship, and watch the atom (from Earth), as the spaceship flies away from us. We would measure the lifetime of that atom to be longer than 1 s, and longer and longer as the spaceship goes faster. In fact, if the spaceship reaches the speed of light, the time for decay would be infinite. But if it stopped, the decay would return to $c$. If it turns around and returns, again the decay would get larger and larger, up to infinity.

I hope these examples clarify things a little bit. Answer was probably too long, but since I was unsure about your exact question, it's a little shot-gunny :-)

(and, for experts, I'm totally aware I'm ignoring things about perspective angles and perpendicular travel. I'm just trying to get at the basic behavior of the theory here)

Comment: ok let me put it this way if the faster u go the more mass u have that mean could their be a speed so slow that we would have little to no mass. And maybe we only have mass because we are moving so fast though the univers!

Comment: haha ok I see what you're asking now. The problem is that the basic tenet of relativity is there is no "background coordinate system" for us to say we are at rest with respect to. That's literally what the "relative" in "relativity" means, we can only measure speed with respect to something else, never absolutely. From your perspective, you are not moving, everything else is moving around you. Since you *do* have mass, your approach is inconsistent.